# Populate DropDownListFor with initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to populate a DropDownListFor in my view, but I don't seem to get it working.

My Model

```
public class Warehouse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationList
    {
        get
        {
            DbEntities db = new DbEntities();

            var List = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocID".Trim(), "Desc".Trim());
            return List;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

In my ViewPage I have the following code

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Warehouse>

<!-- some html -->
@foreach(var s in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(p => s.LocationCode, s.LocationList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

I thought by setting `p => s.LocationCode` I set the initial selected value for the dropdownlist (the selected value should be empty if `s.LocationCode == null`), but my result is that all drop-down boxes are have an initial empty value (and when I click on one of them, you see that the dropdownlist is populated).

Comment: There are too many similar question in SO. Look at this one, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034454/create-many-dropdownlistfor-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this will not bind when you submit. You cannot generate form controls in a `foreach` loop because it generates duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model (it also generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. If you inspect the html you will see that its

```
<select name="s.LocationCode" ... >
<select name="s.LocationCode" ... >
```

where as it needs to be

```
<select name="[0].LocationCode" ... >
<select name="[1].LocationCode" ... >
```

Your loop needs to be

```
@model List<MyApp.Models.Warehouse> // must implement IList<T>
....
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].LocationCode, Model[i].LocationList, ...)
```

Another alternative is to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Warehouse`

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Warehouse.cshtml`

```
@model Warehouse
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LocationCode, Model.LocationList, ...)
```

and then in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Warehouse> // can be Enumerable<T>
....
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

Comment: I've tried what you are describing above, but then I can't use SelectList(Model.LocationList because it says my model does not contains a definition.

Comment: Oops - I have just realized your SelectList is actually inside the model (unusual) so in this case it would need to be just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].LocationCode, Model[i].LocationList)` - generating a new `SelectList` is not strictly necessary. The main issue is your incorrect use of a `foreach` loop which will not give 2-way model binding

Comment: I would also consider changing the way you are doing this. Accessing a database in a model like that is not good practice. Makes it impossible to unit test unless you inject it using DI

Comment: Solved it. I've changed my (View) Model to just have `public IEnumberable<SelectListItem>LocationList {get; set;}`. In my controller I populate the list and set the selectedValue. In my View(cshtml) I have `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].LocationCode, Model[i].LocationList, string.Empty, new {@class = "form-control"})` (and changed my foreach loop to a for loop.